# How do I turn on Twitter's two-factor authentication for multiple accounts and one mobile phone?

Tags: twitter, multi-factor-auth

I want to turn on two-factor authentication for the multiple Twitter accounts I manage. I want to enable *Send login verification requests to the Twitter app*.

However Twitter requires a unique cell phone is associated with each account before the the *Send login verification requests to the Twitter app* can be selected.

Not surprisingly I only have 1 cell phone. Is there way around the limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work around this limitation by setting up additional [SMS receiver services](https://www.google.com/search?q=receive%20sms%20service).

**Update:** As @Saeed points out, [Twitter now lets you use](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/two-factor-authentication) a Time-based One Time Password (TOTP) authentication app like Google Authenticator, Authy, Duo Mobile, 1Password, etc. This is more secure and less hassle than SMS.

One app ought to be able to support multiple accounts on the same service. For instance, Google Authenticator shows the login name for each entry.

Comment: Good idea. stackexchange won't allow me to up vote because I've given all my rep to the bounty.

Comment: @TimMurphy bet the farm? I'm glad it helped! Also amused that the SE app's notification abbreviated your reply to 'Good idea. stackexchange won'.

Comment: SMS is not secure as a MFA measure. Please consider to an authentication app like Google authenticator app, Apple authenticator app, Authy, or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can (now) use the same number for Login Verification (2FA)!

[Twitter Login Verification Article](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170388):

> Note: If you manage multiple accounts that use the same phone number, it is possible to use login verification for each account. For added security, we recommend enabling login verification for all of your accounts.

*You can only have SMS Notifications/commands for one account. 2FA (both push & text) worked great in my testing with 2 accounts.*

Email from Twitter after adding same number to second account:

> Your phone number (xxx-xxx-xxxx) has been added to another account.
>
> Is this still your phone number? If not, please update your account (@Handle) with your current phone number.
>
> NOTE: your account (@Handle) can no longer perform SMS commands nor receive certain SMS notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [recipe from IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/recipes/164945-sms-to-google-drive) so every time you receive a SMS it got appended as a new row to a spreadsheet in google drive.

Then is just matter of give access (share the spreadsheet) to whom it needs access to this account.

I wouldn't do this using my personal cellphone for obvious reasons. Instead have "a corporate" cellphone associated to the twitter account that you want to use with 2FA.

To use the recipe you'll need to activate these two channels, just follow the instructions on the site.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but your answer is for a case when multiple people need the SMS. My case is I have multiple twitter accounts but only 1 cellphone.

Comment: @TimMurphy you're right, I completely misread your question. Indeed Jerry101's answer is the best way to go. Cheers ~M